# How can I make my dataflow job smaller?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm calculating a large number of top-n reports from a single data set.  My very small scale tests work fine.  But when I increase the number of top-n reports, the job is rejected as too large.

The job JSON (via --dataflowJobFile) is 19 MB.

This experiment was for 200 top-n reports, and that doesn't even cover all the report types.  At production scale, we'll be processing 10,000+ top-n reports from multiple data sets.

Running concurrent jobs is impractical because work units would need to be split in awkward ways, and the concurrent job limit is only 25.

I can share job ids and job files privately with the GCDF team.

Comment: How do the top-n reports relate? What makes them 200 different top-N reports, rather than just the top-N-per-key for 200 keys?

Comment: The GCDF has job request limit size of 20MB - so this is likely reason for your job being rejected.  What changes in your code when you go from small scale test to the full test?  Also, can you please share job ids?

Comment: Job id:  2016-06-07_18_47_26-16910805709550021335
I can't start the full size job.  This one is just 1/3 size.

Comment: What about Ben's question? Can you instead express the 10,000+ transforms as a single (or a few) paths with 10,000+ keys?

Comment: Details submitted through Trial Support.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is move the size concerns into your data, rather than in the size of your pipeline. From the "control plane" to the "data plane", if you like.

For each subset of your data on which you want to run a report, assign that subset a key. Assuming each of the reports is already per-key, you'll want to build a compound key that includes both the original key as well as the report key. Then you can calculate all top-*n* reports (for a particular *n*) together as a `Top.largestPerKey(n)` on a single `PCollection`.

Suppose you have multiple top-*n* reports for different thresholds, such as top-10, top-100, etc, and the relationship between the *n* and the subset of your data is too complex to just run the largest and prune to get the others. Then you can either run a separate transform for each *n* (still shouldn't be too many) or assemble a [composed combine](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/CombineFns.java#L128) that calculates them all together.